# setInterval fires Ajax call twice every time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JS code:

```
var delay = 5000;

function init() {
    setInterval(getFileCount, delay);
}

function getFileCount() {
    $.get('/notification/course-file-count', function(response) {
        if (response.items.length === 0) {
            return false;
        }

        // Do stuff with response
    });
}
```

On page load I'm calling the `init()` function. The idea is to start the interval and call the `getFileCount()` function every 5 seconds.

So, the interval waits 5s after the page loads and runs, but it **always makes the Ajax call twice**.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

I know the init() function is triggered twice on page load (thanks to the comment by Yury Tarabanko). I don't quite understand, why. The almost-full code:

```
$(function() {
    'use strict';

    function handleCourseNotification() {

        var delay = 5000;

        function init() {
            setInterval(getFileCount, delay);
        }

        function getFileCount() {
            $.get('/notification/course-file-count', function(response) {
                if (response.items.length === 0) {
                    return false;
                }

                updateCourseList(response.items);
            });
        }

        function updateCourseList(items) {
            // update course list...
        }

        return {
            init: init
        };

    }

    if ($('#js-auth-course-list').length) {
        var notificationHandler = handleCourseNotification();
        notificationHandler.init();
    }

});
```

It's a small module, which I initialize after page load, if a specific element is available in the DOM - `$('#js-auth-course-list')`. Why is init called 2 times actually? I directly call it once.

Comment: it's exactly the same call the two times ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly, but I guess so - the HTTP calls look the same.

Comment: I bet you called init twice :)

Comment: can you show code where you call init() ?

Comment: Your above code looks ok. Don't think its making 2 calls. Is there any other code?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I did call it twice, omg. Thanks.

Comment: `var init = function(){setInterval(getFileCount, delay); init = function(){thrown new Error('Oh, no way I did it twice')}` try this :)

Comment: Updated the post for further help. Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: Try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/adminsunil/mwkL67ge/

Comment: init function is inside  function handleCourseNotification() , move the function init outside, at the same level of handleCourseNotification()

Comment: @LuisCardenas The init was all fine. The problem was ridiculous: it was a branch-merge gone wrong, which basically left me with the same JS file loaded twice on the page. Removed the obsolete one and all is OK.

Answer (score 5):

In general, it is not a good idea to call asynchronous calls inside a `setInterval()` because you do not know the exact **response time**. So, you could end up calling the second async function before the response from the first call has returned.

You can try with `setTimeout()` like this:

```
var delay = 5000;
var async = function() {
   $.get('/notification/course-file-count', function(response) {
      if (response.items.length === 0) {
         return false;
      }
      // Do stuff with response

      // Call the async function again
      setTimeout(function() {
        async();
      }, delay);
   });
}

async();
```

Comment: if i am not wrong, setTimeOut only executes once, and he wants to execute it every 5 seconds

Comment: Yes, but on async success, it calls itself again after 5 seconds. So, it is an infinite loop

Comment: This is not the answer or solution about the above question asked.